# Jenkins add permission for composer

Tags: jenkins, composer-php

I have few projects in Jenkins, but I have problem with build this projects.

Everytime Jenkins throw exception :

> rename(/var/lib/jenkins/.composer/cache/composer-temp.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer):
>   Permission denied

When I add permission `chmod -R 777 /usr/local/bin/composer`, then work but for one project. When I try build next project, Jenkins throw this exception.

Jenkins is in sudoers.

What do I need to Jenkins had the permission?

Comment: and is the code that runs the `rename` really executed using `sudo`? What about placing the `composer` phar in some other place (to which the Jenkins user is allowed to write to) that is added to `$PATH`?

Comment: I don't know whether I understood, but rename executed using without sudo. I think about add composer.phar to project directory, but  I want using  composer in usr path to not duplicated file.

Comment: but to write there, you need permissions that you can gain using sudo, yes. But is sudo actually used?

Comment: Actually I not using sudo . Thanks for help.